# Parallel Nature of Reciprocal and Real Lattice Primitive Vectors

Tags: solid-state-physics

In Michael Shur's "Physics of Semiconductor Devices" book, he asserts

> To satisfy $\exp (i\textbf{K}\cdot \textbf{a}) = 1$, the primitive vectors of the reciprocal and real lattices $\textbf{K}_i$ and $\textbf{a}_j$ must satisfy the following conditions: $$ \textbf{K}_i\cdot\textbf{a}_j = 2\pi \delta_{ij}\hspace{1cm} ( 1 ) $$

I am currently interpreting this to mean that the primitive vectors of the reciprocal lattice are parallel to one another. This in itself does make a good amount of sense, as the Bloch waves are periodic in the same way that the crystal lattice itself is. My question is, **why is this strictly necessary?** It seems that there could be any number of different solutions that would not imply (1), such as how $$ \textbf{K}\cdot\textbf{a} = 2\pi m,\hspace{1cm}m \in \mathbb{N} $$
Could lead to
$$ \sum_i\sum_j\textbf{K}_i\cdot n_j\textbf{a}_j = 2\pi \sum_i\sum_j m_{ij},\hspace{1cm}m_{ij} \in \mathbb{N} $$
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not quite correct to interpret this as the real and reciprocal vectors being necessarily parallel. It only means that the projection of one reciprocal vector onto one of the real space vectors is $2\pi $ while the other real space vectors are orthogonal to that reciprocal vector.
It is correct that the condition can be satisfied by anything that will result in an integer multiple of $2\pi $, but since the statement concerns primitive vectors the definition requires that those are of minimal length, which results in a projection with length $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the word primitive is there for. It gives you the specific choice of $m=1$ so you can choose a convenient basis for the lattice of possible K. Of course if you get $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$ all satisfying $e^{i K_i \cdot a}=1$ for all real space lattice vectors a, then $n_1 K_1+n_2 K_1+n_3 K_3$ will too. But they will likely be uglier to write down. Might as well use the basis you already have. That is the primitive one.